# 'C-style' strings in Python

Tags: python, string, null

A very popular question is how to reverse a C-Style string. The C-Style string by definition is a string that is terminated by a null('\0'). Using C(or maybe C++), it is possible to use pointers to manipulate the string to reverse its contents in-place.

If somebody asks the question, "How do you reverse a C-style string in Python?", what would some of the possible answers be?

Thanks

Comment: What's you definition of a "C-Style string" in Python? A Python string with a trailing `\x00`? Or something that comes from a C extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you need to "reverse a C-style string in Python", I think the end result must also be a c-style string.**

That is how I would understand the question, but the above answers do *not* support this.

See the interactive session below:

```
>>> 
>>> original = "abc\0"
>>> finish_correct = "cba\0"
>>> original
'abc\x00'
>>> finish_correct
'cba\x00'
>>> 
>>> answer = original[:-1]  # remove final null
>>> answer = answer[::-1]  # reverse string
>>> # Extended slice syntax:  [begin:end:step]
>>> # So, [::-1] means take whole string, but in reverse.
>>> answer
'cba'
>>> answer = answer + "\0"
>>> answer
'cba\x00'
>>> answer == finish_correct
True
```

Also note, Python strings are immutable.  This means that they can never be changed.  You can make new strings that are assigned to the same variable name, but the in-memory image for a given strings will never change.  Thus, the notion of "reverse a string in place" can not happen in Python.

**Hope this helps.**  If so, please up-vote and accept the answer. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Python doesn't use C-style strings; Python strings can contain an embedded NUL, so C-style strings are not used, but rather an explicit length.

```
>>> 'abc\0def'[::-1]
'fed\x00cba'
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain your snippet here? Is the '\0' the embedded NUL that you are referring to?

Comment: It uses extended slicing to return a sequence from the beginning to the end of the source sequence, but in reverse order. The `\0` in the string is indeed an embedded NUL. http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html

Comment: `'abc\0def'` is not a c-style string, nor is `'fed\x00cba'`.

Comment: @martineau: *Again*, Python does. Not. Have. C-style strings.

Comment: @martineau: what *is* a C-style string, in your opinion?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, @Eli Bendersky: In my opinion a C-style string would be one whose last byte was a zero character, aka a NUL byte, which *is* certainly possible to put into a Python string. Following that convention implies that there are no characters following the '\0' and that a reversed version of one would only swap the other characters around, i.e. `"?FTW\0"` would become `"WTF?\0"`, just as they would in a C program using arrays of the char. Since Python strings are immutable, a better emulation would store them in a `list` or the recently added `bytearray` type.

Answer (score 3):

Since C doesn't have a string type, it represents character strings as pointers to `char`, where the last byte (assuming ASCII, not wide-characters) is `\0`. It's a *representation*. By the way, this default implementation has the deficiency that `\0` can't be part of such a string. If that's needed, a different representation is required (such as representing a string as a pointer + a length integer).

Python, OTOH has a string type, and it's opaque to the user how this type is represented. Therefore, a "C-style string" is a meaningless concept in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Python strings are [immutable](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-python-strings-immutable.htm). You could emulate a C-style string with a table of chars, but I don't see why you would bother.

But if you did have a C-style "string" (ie table of characters), then all you'd need to do is swap s[i] with s[len(s)-i-1]:

```
for i in range(0, len(a) - 2):
    a[i], a[len(a) - 1 - i] = a[len(a) - 1 - i], a[i]
```

(if a is your C-style string)

Note how you don't need a temporary variable(granted you don't need one in C either, considering how you could use the null character as a temp space).

Comment: @delnan: It would be a little better if the answer's code had been indented properly (the code shown is not syntactically correct Python). It could be have been made even more sensible if some optional whitespace added was added. That said, it may still be hard to understand what or how clearly written code is doing its work and accomplishing its task unless you understand the algorithm involved.